# how to get the value of an object in array using laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, key, union

I want to change the output of this array to another array using laravel.
here is the actual array :
[the actuel array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kwlS.png)

**array:4 [▼ 0 => {#2569 ▶ +"count": 6 } 1 => {#2578 ▶ +"count": 7 }
2 => {#2577 ▶ +"count": 1 } 3 => {#2576 ▶ +"count": 0 } ]**

what I want to display instead :

**array:4 [
'A':6,
'B':7,
'C':0,
'D':1
]**

here is my source code.

```
$filter = ["A","B","C","D"];
if(user()->hasRole('admin')){
                   $projects = DB::table('projects AS p')->select(DB::raw('count(p.id) as count'))->where('p.alphabet','=','A')
                       ->union(DB::table('projects AS p')->select(DB::raw('count(p.id) as count'))->where('p.alphabet','=','B'))
                       ->union(DB::table('projects AS p')->select(DB::raw('count(p.id) as count'))->where('p.alphabet','=','C'))
                   ->union(DB::table('projects AS D')->select(DB::raw('count(p.id) as count'))->where('p.alphabet','=','C'));}
return ($projects->get()->toArray());
```

the output of
**print_r($projects->get()->toArray())** is :
**Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 6 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 7 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 1 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [count] => 0 ) )**

any help please?

Comment: Why not change the name in the SQL Query itself? e.g: `DB::raw('count(yp.id) as ready')`?

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($projectsCount->get()->toArray())`; and paste the output in the question?

Comment: I'm a little rusty when it comes to Laravel, but from what I recall, you should be able to do it by changing your query builder to look [like this](https://i.imgur.com/446ZeuK.png). You would be returning a two column table with this, and your array would be something [like this](https://i.imgur.com/vJoX7LC.png).

Comment: thank you for your response but i need to change the array to just one key,value couple i just want to have an array that contains this structure : array ["status":value] i mean the output should be sthg like that : array:4 [ 'ready':6, 'in_progress':7, 'done':0, 'closed':1 ] @FiddlingAway

Comment: Just [loop through it](https://i.imgur.com/PCX25YH.png) to get it to be like that.

Comment: i had this error : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array @FiddlingAway

Comment: Did you do this first? `$dbArr = $projectsCount->get()->toArray()`?

Comment: yes i did @FiddlingAway

Comment: What do you get if you do this? `$dbArr = $projectsCount->get()->toArray(); var_dump($dbArr);`

Comment: The looping would still do the trick - you would just use the arrow notation, since it's an array of objects, and not an array of arrays. See [this image](https://i.imgur.com/hMcSk8h.png) to get a better idea.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can post the way you solved it (post it as an answer to your question), just in case anyone else has the same issue - they probably won't read the comments, but they'll surely see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(user()->hasRole('admin')){
                   $projects = DB::table('projects AS p')->select(DB::raw(" 'A' as alphabet, count(p.id) as occurrences"))->where('p.alphabet','=','A')
                       ->union(DB::table('projects AS p')->select(DB::raw(" 'B' as alphabet, count(p.id) as B"))->where('p.alphabet','=','B'))
                       ->union(DB::table('projects AS p')->select(DB::raw(" 'C' as alphabet, count(p.id) as C"))->where('p.alphabet','=','C'))
                       ->union(DB::table('projects AS p')->select(DB::raw(" 'D' as alphabet, count(p.id) as D"))->where('p.alphabet','=','D'));

                $result=$projects->get()->toArray();
                $newArr = array();
                foreach ($result as $pair) {
                    $newArr[$pair->alphabet] = $pair->occurrences;
                }
                dd($newArr);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).